# Did Amon die in Root A?

Tags: tokyo-ghoul

In *Tokyo Ghoul: Root A*, they showed Amon collapse and then Kaneki left him. Later when Akira reached him, she started crying. However, they never confirmed whether or not he's really dead and they don't show him after he collapses.

Did Amon die in *Root A*?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As for whether or not Amon died in ***Tokyo Ghoul: Root A*** is unclear as the events you describe is all we get with regards to Amon's injury.

However, in *Tokyo Ghoul:re* manga:

> Amon is reported "killed in action" however his body is never recovered. Later it is discovered that Amon was captured by Aogiri and is experimented on by Dr.Kanou. He is given the name "Owl 27" as he inherits Owl's [kagune](http://tokyoghoul.wikia.com/wiki/Kagune), with a [kakugen](http://tokyoghoul.wikia.com/wiki/Kakugan) in his right eye. Just like Kaneki, Amon is now a half-ghoul and is in fact not dead. [Source](http://tokyoghoul.wikia.com/wiki/Koutarou_Amon)

Comment: Thanks for answering my question! Your answer has been very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure he's still alive.

I know this isn't much, but in the new episode of *Tokyo Ghoul:re*, a tall man with black hair similar to Amon and wearing a cloak is seen as he saved Saiko. I'm really positive that this is Amon. Who else would it be and why would they cover him up so much.

Answer (score -1):

He is dead.

It's said in episode 10, he died on action for unknown reasons during the battle. He got stabbed and died that day.

Comment: He was marked Killed in action, but his body was not recovered, just the arm Kaneki severed during their fight. His body which was close to the arm vanished, but he was alive before he fell unconscious, and thus it was never actually confirmed if he died or not.